# Angular: pass JS type 'Number' to an HTTP response

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, angular-httpclient

I'm working on a MEAN app (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node). I want to make a GET route in Express that uses Mongo's `countDocuments()` method to return the total number of entries in a collection.

GET route:

```
app.get('/total', (req, res) => {
  collection.countDocuments({}, function(err, num) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    var total = {'total' : num}
    res.send(total);
  });
});
```

I made the `total` object because it's my understanding that Angular's `HttpClient` module only works with data if it's formatted in JSON. I tried to pass `num` directly as `res.send(num)` but it wouldn't work. I think it's because `typeof(num)` returns `Number` and not `Object`.

The route above works but making the `total` object seems like a hack to me. Is there a more efficient way to pass something of type `Number` so that it's ready to be consumed by Angular?

Here is the relevant Angular component code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  total: object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:1337/total').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.total = data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you change your total variable to {total: num}; removing quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send a number in `res.send` in `express`, It takes it as status code so sending a number of type `Number` is not allowed, There are 2 solutions.

### Solution: 1

```
var result = 5;
res.send(result.toString());
```

Sent it as string, And in Client side use `parseInt`.

### Solution: 2

```
var result = 5;
res.send({result}); //Iquivalent to { result: 5 }
```

Send an object as you mentioned.